# Spring Boot Sqlite query dates

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate

I have a Raspberry Pi temperature logger using a Sqlite database which is working great with my embedded C++ Civetweb application.

I thought I'd have some fun trying to get something hooked up with Spring Boot. I can get some queries working, but almost nothing I try works with querying dates.

I'm using *org.xerial sqlite-jdbc 3.36.0.3* and *com.enigmabridge hibernate4-sqlite-dialect 0.1.2* for setting up the sqlite datasource.

On my Pi, my main query to return data and show a temperature graph for the last day is:

```
SELECT timestamp, temp, id FROM temps WHERE timestamp > datetime('now', 'localtime', '-1 days');
```

but this type of query doesn't seem to work with JPA as the number of days to query is inside the single quote string literal, so any parameters are passed as is. It will return data if I directly specify the days in the query, but I want to pass that as a param.

So I had a go at querying between two dates in Spring Boot like so:

```
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate start = end.minusDays(2);

return temperatureRepository.findTemperaturesBetweenDates(start, end);
```

using this in the repository:

```
@Query("SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp between :startDate AND :endDate")
List<Temperature> findTemperaturesBetweenDates(@Param(value="startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param(value="endDate") LocalDate endDate);
```

This query returns no results. Again, specifying the dates directly in single quotes in the query without a parameter works, and data is returned. I have also tried nativeQuery but that gives the same results.

Changing the logging level on Hibernate to trace, I can see the parameters that are being used, and it seems to be converting the dates into epoch time.

> ```
> /* SELECT
>     op 
> FROM
>     Temperature op 
> WHERE
>     timestamp between :startDate AND :endDate */ select
>         temperatur0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_,
>         temperatur0_.id as id2_0_,
>         temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_ 
>     from
>         temps temperatur0_ 
>     where
>         timestamp between ? and ? Hibernate: 
> /* SELECT
>     op 
> FROM
>     Temperature op 
> WHERE
>     timestamp between :startDate AND :endDate */ select
>         temperatur0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_,
>         temperatur0_.id as id2_0_,
>         temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_ 
>     from
>         temps temperatur0_ 
>     where
>         timestamp between ? and ?
> ```

> 2022-06-06 23:18:45.393 DEBUG 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Creating new JDBC
> DriverManager Connection to
> [jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/sqlTemplog.db] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394
> TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Registering statement [/*
> SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp between :startDate AND
> :endDate */ select temperatur0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_,
> temperatur0_.id as id2_0_, temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_ from temps
> temperatur0_ where timestamp between ? and ?   parameters=null]
> 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : Registering last query
> statement [/* SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp between
> :startDate AND :endDate */ select temperatur0_.timestamp as
> timestam1_0_, temperatur0_.id as id2_0_, temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_
> from temps temperatur0_ where timestamp between ? and ?
>
> parameters=null] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
> parameter [1] as [DATE] - [**2022-06-04**] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE
> 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      :
> binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [**2022-06-06**] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394
> TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader
>
> : Bound [3] parameters total 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   :
> Registering result set [org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet@23105e31]
> 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Processing result set
> 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Done processing result set
> (0 rows) 2022-06-06 23:18:45.394 TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Total objects hydrated: 0
> 2022-06-06 23:18:45.395 TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Releasing statement [/*
> SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp between :startDate AND
> :endDate */ select temperatur0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_,
> temperatur0_.id as id2_0_, temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_ from temps
> temperatur0_ where timestamp between ? and ?
>
> parameters=[**1654297200000**, **1654470000000**]] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.395
> TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Closing result set
> [org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet@23105e31] 2022-06-06 23:18:45.395
> TRACE 9328 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
> o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : Closing prepared statement
> [/* SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp between :startDate
> AND :endDate */ select temperatur0_.timestamp as timestam1_0_,
> temperatur0_.id as id2_0_, temperatur0_.temp as temp3_0_ from temps
> temperatur0_ where timestamp between ? and ?
> parameters=[**1654297200000**, **1654470000000**]]

The only way I've managed to get it working is by using unixepoch in the query, and converting the parameter inside Sqlite:

```
@Query(value =("select timestamp, id, temp from temps where timestamp between DATETIME(ROUND(:startDate / 1000), 'unixepoch') AND DATETIME(ROUND(:endDate / 1000), 'unixepoch')"), nativeQuery = true)
List<Temperature> findTemperaturesTest(@Param(value="startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param(value="endDate") LocalDate endDate);
```

Any ideas how to get the date queries working correctly with Spring Boot and Sqlite?
Thanks

**Edit:**

Ok, so just managed to get the -X days part working, however I do have other queries that combine +/- days and a date, but still no luck with passing a date to the query correctly.

```
@Query("SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE id between 1 and 4 AND timestamp > datetime('now', 'localtime', '-' || :days || ' days')")
List<Temperature> findTemperaturesMinusDays(@Param(value="days") int days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, so this all seems to come down to the way that Sqlite stores dates. My database has been storing the timestamp field as a string such as "2022-06-07 23:44:19", and most databases store dates as unix time.

No problem, I'll just tell it to convert a LocalDateTime to a String when it queries the database. Hmm, maybe not quite that easy. I tried @Converter, @Type, a few other things that I have problem forgotten. None of that worked.

My first semi-successful attempt was to change the data type in the class to a String, and convert in the getter. But that meant that the @Query params also had to be passed as a String. Not great.

So, my solution is a custom repository which converts a LocalDateTime to a String and sets these as parameters in the query.

```
public class TemperatureRepositoryImpl implements TemperatureRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Temperature> findTemperaturesBetweenDates(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT timestamp, temp, id FROM temps WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate");

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String startDateString = startDate.format(formatter);
        String endDateString = endDate.format(formatter);

        query.setParameter("startDate", startDateString);
        query.setParameter("endDate", endDateString);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Nearly had it with that. Couple of issues - didn't work with the interface repository, only the implementation, and dates didn't include the time. Finally have it working with a TypedQuery:

```
    public List<Temperature> findTemperaturesBetweenDates(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
        TypedQuery<Temperature> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT op FROM Temperature op WHERE timestamp BETWEEN date(:startDate) AND date(:endDate)", Temperature.class);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String startDateString = startDate.format(formatter);
        String endDateString = endDate.format(formatter);

        query.setParameter("startDate", startDateString);
        query.setParameter("endDate", endDateString);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise I had autowired the Impl repository instead of the interface. Switching to that and now I get this error:
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.sql.Date] to type [model.Temperature]

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a date type like other databases; see [doco](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). For my spring-boot 3.X and hibernate 6.x application, I had to explicitly configure the SQLite driver to consider my "timestamp" column to be treated as `TEXT` by setting the `date_class` property.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:sqlite:sample.db?date_class=TEXT
```